# Return anything from Insert in Room Android with autoGenerate = false

Tags: android, android-room

I am inserting a user in room with an string id, All I want is to get something in return so that I can update the UI state immediately after that. I know that if autoGenerate = true then Room can return Long as id but I could not find solution of manual id.

```kotlin
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun createUser(userTable: UserTable) // something I want to return
}
```

```kotlin
@Entity
data class UserTable (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val userId : String,
    val name   : String
)
```

Comment: Your question is not clearly understood. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your UserDao to return the inserted row ID. You can use the @Insert annotation to get the row ID by defining a return type of Long. If you want to know if the user was added successfully, you can check if the returned ID is greater than 0.

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun createUser(userTable: UserTable): Long
}
```

When inserting a new user, you can check the return value to determine if the user was added successfully. If the return value is greater than 0, it means the user was successfully inserted, and the returned value is the generated primary key. If the return value is 0, it means the insertion was ignored due to a conflict.

```
val user = UserTable(userId = "12345", name = "John Doe")
val userId = userDao.createUser(user)

if (userId > 0) {
    // User added successfully, and userId is the generated primary key }
} else {
    // User insertion was ignored due to a conflict }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it gave me the index or row number which is enough.

Comment: @kallis what is returned is the **rowid** which is unique to a row and correctly it is the generated key. If you have a non integer type primary key (you have String) the value is not generated. If the primary key is an integer type then the column is an alias of the **rowid**, which is generated unless a value is specified. See https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html (Room doesn't offer annotations/options for WITHOUT ROWID tables),